# What is a weak solution living in a dual space?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

Recently, I saw a regularity theorem concerning weak solutions to an elliptic equation. I found it in the book *Geometric Relativity* written by Dan A. Lee, and its statement is vague and intricate to me. Here it goes.

> Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, $X$ a smooth vector field on $M$, and $f$ a smooth function on $M$. And we define a second-order elliptic operator $L$ by
> $$L(u)=-\Delta u+\langle X,\nabla u\rangle+fu,$$
> where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian.
>
> **Theorem A.5** (Interior elliptic regularity for weak solutions). *Given $u$ in the dual space of $C_c^k(\mathrm{Int}M)$ for some $k\geq 2$, if $L(u)$ is smooth, then $u$ is smooth on $\mathrm{Int}M$.*

The theorem is set within a Riemannian manifold, but feel free to work in an open bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if you want to give a quick example.

So my question is, **why is $u$ given in the dual space of a function space**? I've read some PDE books, such as the ones written by Lawrence C. Evans and Jurgen Jost, but none of them defines weak solutions in the setting of dual spaces. Mostly they define a weak solution to a PDE as a function in a Sobolev space that solves a variant of the PDE. I googled the question but didn't get much. How can a linear functional become a weak solution? What is it really? Thanks very much.

Comment: The dual space of $C^k_c$ (with appropriate topology - not sure what it would be in this space) can be identified with a function space (for example, dual of $L^p$ can be identified with $L^q$, so the theorem is true for any function $u$ in this function space.

Comment: He might be pointing towards solutions in the distributional sence.

Comment: @Martin Thanks, Martin. There is indeed a small paragraph written before the theorem, but I don't see any dual vectors mentioned in the sentences. Anyway, Lee said that $L(u)=f$ in the weak sense if $\langle u,L^*(\phi)\rangle=\langle f,\phi\rangle$ for all test functions $\phi$, where $L^*$ denotes the adjoint operator and the angle brackets represent the pairing between distributions and test functions. This above is all I got before the theorem. Does it help any? Thank you.

Comment: You can define the Sobolev spaces as functions in $L^p$ whose weak derivative, thought as a distribution (i.e., a element on the dual of $C_{0}^{\infty}$) are indeed functions, and live in L^p. This is in Lieb and Loss' Analysis book :)

Comment: See also Theorem 3.12 in Sobolev Spaces by Adams and Fournier.

Comment: @Sebathon Thank you, Sebathon. Although I still have some questions about the regularity theory of distributions, the books you recommended do make me feel more comfortable with the theorem. Thanks a lot